# Installing a plugin into Drone CI (the Trigger plugin)

Tags: drone.io

I'm new to Drone, and I want to use my first plugin, namely this one: http://addons.drone.io/trigger/

However, the Drone documentation doesn't really explain how to install plugins. What I've done is copy the example yaml into my .drone.yml, resulting in this (obviously I've censored the sensitive information, but every single key is the same as the real document):

```
pipeline:
    build:
        image: docker
        commands:
            - docker build .
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    notify:
        downstream:
            image: plugins/trigger
            server: http://my.drone.server
            repositories:
              - My/Repo
            token: mytoken
```

However, when I push this, Drone gives me the error:

```
ERROR: Invalid or missing image
```

If I put the image in, as in

```
notify:
    image: plugins/trigger
    downstream:
```

I get:

```
plugins/trigger not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

Am I supposed to build a docker container for each plugin? How do I get access to this plugin?

Comment: note that http://addons.drone.io was moved to http://plugins.drone.io, which has more accurate and up-to-date information.

Comment: Oh, no wonder I was confused. Can you pull down the old outdated site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an "image not found" error is because there is no such image called `plugins/trigger` in the docker registry. Instead I think you probably want the `plugins/downstream` image [1][2].

[1] http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-downstream/ 
[2] https://hub.docker.com/r/plugins/downstream/